# When should i use dot (.) after require('module') in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this authenticate middleware and i exported this

```html
var {User} = require('./../model/user');

var authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
    var token = req.header('x-auth');
    User.findByToken(token).then((user) => {
        if (!user) return Promise.reject();
        req.user = user;
        req.token = token;
        next();
    }).catch((err) => res.status(401).send());
}

module.exports = {authenticate};
```

In server.js `var authenticate = require('./middleware/authenticate')`
didnt work.

why should i need to add this

`var authenticate = require('./middleware/authenticate').authenticate;`

If i do not add .authenticate after require it logs the error as

> Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

Comment: If you have just one function(as in your case) then just do `module.exports = authenticate;`.

Comment: And if you have multiple functions in a file then you should do  `module.exports = {func1, func2, ...};` and at the time of `require()`ing them just do `const funcs = require('/path/to/module')` and use them like `funcs.func1();`.

Comment: you are exporting an object `{}`, with a property `authenticate` - to access this exported function you need to use the usual "accessing an object property" method

Comment: @Rajesh - I think you missed the *point* (pun intended)

Comment: OMG ! now i got it ! Thanks to all ! I owe you all buddies !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules are the fundamental building block of the code structure in Javascript. You can use them to structure your code.
When you write

```
module.exports = someobject
```

you are actually defining a public interface to the clients of your module.

Now consider the above statement which fundamentally has two parts :-
1) There is a variable name  (Left  hand side)
2) There is an object.       (Right hand side)

Your statement simply associates an object with a variable name.
You can use this statement to associate anything to your variable (module.exports).

So lets now come to your problem

```
 //authenticate.js
 // some code
 module.exports = {authenticate};  // your interface is pointing to an object

//server.js

var authenticate = require('./middleware/authenticate');

/* after this statement your module.exports is pointing to {authenticate} object which is not a callable.
You actually wants to access the the authenticate function which lies inside /this object therefore when you do*/


var authenticate = require('./middleware/authenticate').authenticate 
// it works because you are now accessing the function inside the object which is callable.
```

Comment: Thanks buddy ! I got it now ! your answer is more clear so i will accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

`module.exports = {authenticate};`

You are exporting an object `{ authenticate: authenticate }`, but the middleware requires a function which is stored in `authenticate` property of the exported object, that is why `.authenticate` works correctly. You may export the function only e.g.

`module.exports = authenticate;`

then you won't need a dot, to put it in your words.